# Error when writing filepath to app.config during windows service installation vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, windows-installer, app-config, custom-action

I'm trying to write a user defined filepath to my app.config file.

When i enter c:\ as the filepath it writes it to my xml file but adds and extra /

Im not too sure why its happening? i have all the correct custom actions set up and my install method is as follows:

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Writing to the root of a disk is always wrong. Post the *actual code* that you're using if you want people to do more than guess in their answers.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash has a special meaning. Maybe you need to escape the backslashes:

```
<add key="param1" value="c:\\Users\\Joe\\Desktop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to UAC, as admin rights would be required to write to the root of C: if using win7 or potentially vista.